React Natvie App on iOS crashes when typing or making the input field active. How to prevent it?
When I test the app locally, either on, simulator or iPhone, it works correctly but when deployed to the TestFlight env. It crashes when making the input field active e.g. when entering the signin credentials. This is what the screen where the bug appears looks like:
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  NativeModules,
  Text,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ScrollView,
  Platform,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {styled} from 'nativewind';
import {LoginForm, LogoImage} from '@/components';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

const StyledText = styled(Text);
const StyledView = styled(View);

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const {t} = useTranslation();

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      style={{flex: 1}}>
      <StyledView className="flex-1 justify-start items-center bg-darkPurple py-12">
        <StyledText className="text-slate-200 text-3xl mb-4 font-light">
          {t('Logowanie')}
        </StyledText>
        <LogoImage size={2} classes="mb-24" />
        <LoginForm />
      </StyledView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;

I tried some small order manipulations, like switching the  with  but the error still occurs. :(

can u please share the code of the loginform?
